# Unknown method error using FB.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm running into an issue using the FB.ui. It is a pretty simple implementation but every time I try it I get "API Error Code: 3", "API Error Description: Unknown method".

Here is an exact copy and paste with dummy data of what I am using to get this error.

```
function fbSend(){
        FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            name: 'Me testing name',
            link: 'http://google.ca',
            picture: 'http://www.gravitationalfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/google+logo-75x75.png',
            description: 'Me is testing description'
        });
    };
```

I'm not using any Oauth/ requesting user permissions.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance
Smccullough

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. However, I can get send to work using the javascript test console. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/
Clcik examples, and choose FB.ui feed then change the method to "send" instead of feed and it works. But I can't figure out what is different on the console than in my code.

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon its very odd, no? I was just trying the console tool just before noticing your comment. I logged an issue with Facebook, hopefully we'll hear back soon. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/178705512204936

Comment: @PlasticSturgeon I just found a quick fix! There was a Facebook bug entered in July and still hasn't been addressed. 
The 'Send Dialog' only works with display: 'popup' everything else throws errors.

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18942

Answer (score 3):

There is a filed bug about it here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18942

Use the option display: "popup" to make it work